# How to identify the type of a selected object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am placing Text, Image and Shapes on canvas using Fabric.js. I have made Three different Edit-Panels for all three. When user select text I want to show text panel. like wise for image and shapes.

How to identify type of selected Object?

Comment: plz post some code dat you tried

Comment: I tried manully setting and fetching canvas.getActiveObject().get('type') , but is there any other way

Answer (score 26):

`canvas.getActiveObject().get('type')` as simmi simmi said is correct. You can also listen to events:

```
function onObjectSelected(e) {
  console.log(e.target.get('type'));
}
canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);
```

Comment: I am looking for deselected events and found nice demo on fabric.js site - http://fabricjs.com/events/

Answer (score 11):

I solved this issue using following code::

```
  if(canvas.getActiveObject().get('type')==="text")
        {
            //Display text panel
            console.log('text panel Displayed');
            $("#Image_left_panel").css("display", "none");
            $("#shape_left_panel").css("display", "none");
            //$("#left_panel").css("display", "block");
        }
        else if(canvas.getActiveObject().get('type')==="Image")
        {
            //Display Image Panel
            console.log('Image Panel Displayed');
            $("#Image_left_panel").css("display", "block");
            $("#shape_left_panel").css("display", "none");
            $("#left_panel").css("display", "none");
        }
        else
        {

        }


        });
```

Comment: What about any shape? `.get('type')` returns 'rect', 'circle', etc.

Comment: @PaulRedmond yes it returns exact object type. rect, circle, Image, ...

Comment: For those working with later versions of fabric js. I think you mean object.get('type') === 'textbox' not 'text'

Answer (score 10):

Try  **`isType()`**

Sample function for getting selected objects

```
function onObjectSelected(o){
    //activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject()
    activeObject = o.target;

    if(activeObject.isType('text')){
       //display text logic
    }
    else if(activeObject.isType('image')){
      //display image
    }
    else if( activeObject.isType('xyz')){
      //display shape logic
    }
}

canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);
```

Comment: For those working with later versions of fabric js. I think you mean object.get('type') === 'textbox' not 'text'

Answer (score 7):

In fabricjs 3.4 and above, to get the object type, just use:

```
var objType = canvas.getActiveObject().type;
```

On IText object, the above will return: **i-text**

On image, it will return: **image**

**Usage:**

Call the following function which adds an additional check to make sure **type** is a property of the active element.

**Note:** not all elements have the **type** property.

```js
 canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);

 function onObjectSelected() { 
     // check if type is a property of active element
     var objType = (canvas.getActiveObject().type ? canvas.getActiveObject().type : "");

     // your code to process the object
}
```